# (Swift) How to calculate the seconds between a time (string) and the time of a button clicked?

Tags: swift, xcode, date, time, calculator

Im new to programming, so I would be very happy if somebody could help me

I want to create a calculator which calculates the seconds which have passed between a certain time (i. e. „03:30“) and the current time (when the Button is clicked).

For example:

Selected time = „00:30“ (in TextField)

Time when Button is clicked = 04:00

Output (seconds passed) = 1800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have current hour, minute and seconds according to your timezone.
I would use like this.

```
var myCalendar = Calendar.current
var date1 = Date()
func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    date1 = Date()
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let date2 = Date();
    let hour = myCalendar.component(.hour, from: date2)
    let minute = myCalendar.component(.minute, from: date2)
    let second = myCalendar.component(.second, from: date2)
    print("Time when Button is clicked: "\(hour)":"\(minute))
    print("Seconds passed: "\(date2.timeIntervalSinceNow-date1.timeIntervalSinceNow))
}
```

Comment: Setting the `timeZone` for the `Calendar.current` is unnecessary. It defaults to the device time zone.

Comment: And `date1` shouldn't be a local variable of `viewDidLoad`. And if you implement `viewDidLoad`, make sure to call `super.viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Didn't know about them, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much! But is there a way to set for example one date to a certain time? (i.e. 00:00 or 00:30)?

Comment: Ahh I got it. I had to set one date like that: date1 = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())

Comment: and add a ! in seconds passed